# interpreting aspects of rotational motion conceptually

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics

**Level** - First Year Physics University

I don't understand the concept of [angular momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum), conceptually. What is it? if I were to explain it how would I go about doing that? without having to explain it mathematically.

I am also a bit disorientated by it's direction relative to the direction and or plane of rotation, although I understand that the right hand rule applies but conceptually to me it doesn't make any sense. Feel free to include mathematical formulas, and discuss angular velocity, angular acceleration and other components in relation to rotational motion.

Comment: I'd advice u to change your name first.Don't feel lost or you'll never find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like linear momentum, angular moment is used to describe the degree of resistance to change in angular motion.

There are two types of changes to consider. a) Change in rotation speed and b) Change in rotation direction. I think the first is kind of trivial to understand, but the second is a little more tricky. If you have vector that is riding on a rotating body, which direction does the vector *change*? You need  the right hand rule to figure it out as it is a cross product.

Look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame

and

http://www.envsci.rutgers.edu/~broccoli/dynamics_lectures/lect_06_dyn12_mom_eq_rot.pdf

Hope this helps.